# how plot two slopes for one curve

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have one curve in Matlab. I want to plot two slopes; the first slop is for points 1,2,3 and 4. The second slope is to plot the rest of the points. See figure:

[image]

Comment: Do you already have the slopes? Do you know how to obtain them? What method are you using? Linear fit using Least squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "plot two slopes", I will assume that you mean you want to plot the lines that best approximate the two parts of your data. To do so you will need to perform a curve fitting procedure such as least squares. For more information on least squares approximation in MATLAB see this question: [How do I use the least squares approximation in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832429/how-do-i-use-the-least-squares-approximation-in-matlab)

I will assume that your data is stored in the vectors `x` and `y`.

```
%//number of points for the first part of the curve:
n=4;

%// Separate (x,y) into (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)
x1 = x(1:n); x2=x(n+1:end);
y1 = y(1:n); y2=y(n+1:end);

%// fit a line y=A1*x+A2 to the first set of points:
M=[x1(:) ones(length(x1),1)];
A = M\y1(:); %//A(1) is your slope, A(2) is your y-intercept

%// fit a line y=B1*x+B2 to the second set of points:
M=[x2(:) ones(length(x2),1)];
B = M\y2(:); %//B(1) is your slope, B(2) is your y-intercept

%//Plot:
hold on
fplot(@(x)A(1)*x+A(2),[min(x1) max(x1)])
fplot(@(x)B(1)*x+B(2),[min(x2) max(x2)])
```

Comment: Some corrections in the code are:
x1 = x(1:n); x2=x(n+1:end);
y1 = y(1:n); y2=y(n+1:end);



%//Plot:
plot(x1,y1,'o'); hold on; plot (x1, A(1)*x1+A(2))

plot(x2,y2,'o'); hold on; plot (x2, B(1)*x2+B(2))

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo involving `y1` and `y2` assignments. My plot commands work fine but may not show what you want. You should obviously choose your own plotting methods based on what you want to display.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I appreciate your efforts Doug Lipinski