# Least Squares Solution and Distance in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, least-squares

1. Find the least squares solutions of the systems A*x=b and A*x=c.
2. If x is the least squares solution of A*x=b, find the L2 distance of A*x from b. Similarly, if x is the least squares solution of A*x=c, find the L2 distance of A*x from c.

My goal is to do this using matlab, but I'm having some troubles. My matrices are as follows:

> A = [ones(1000,1), repmat([2,0]', 500, 1)];
>
> b = [repmat([2,4]',500,1)];
>
> c = [repmat([1,2,3,4]',250,1)];

It suggests that I use the regress command, but I'm completely uncertain how to go about this particular problem.

Comment: Read `doc \ `  and `doc norm`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the least squares approximation in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832429/how-do-i-use-the-least-squares-approximation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

For a set of euqations  Ax=b, the x that yields least square error is pseudo-inverse of A times b. In Matlab command, it's

```
x_hat = pinv(A) * b
```

To obtain L2 distance of Ax and b, use norm

```
norm(A*x_hat - b)
```

Comment: `pinv(A)*b` is less efficient and less numerically stable than `A\b`.